# accept a connection inside a pthread

Tags: linux, sockets, pthreads

I hope someone can help me with my problem.
I trying to make a client/server FTP application using C,

my program implementation is like this :

```
main()
{
1)create socket
2)bind on port 8888
3)listen
5) while(accept)
  { 
    5) create  pthread1 to handle the connection using function1
    6)join the pthread1
  }
}

function 1()
{
1)take the file descriptor from the main
2) discusses with client using the descriptor (send/recv)
3) create pthread2 to handle data exchange
4) join the pthread 2
5)free the descriptor
}
function 2()
{
1)create socket
2)bind on port 8889
3)listen
4)accept
}
```

MY PROBLEM :
-When i try the first client ,everything is OK, TWO connections are well done !
-When i try the second client, the first connection is OK,but the second one gives a BIND error !!
-I dont really know what's the problem. 
-Thank u for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) It seems to me that you are only going to have one client thread (pthread1) running at a time.  In `main()` you are going to block on `pthread_join` until the first thread is done. So if you continue down this road you will either have to create those threads as detached or use an alternative method to join thread1. Or, better yet, use a thread pool.

(2)  My guess is your 2nd `bind` is failing because it is already in use after the 1st connection.  Even if the 1st connection closes it before a 2nd connection is established there is time lag before it becomes available for use again.  You can get around this lag but it is not the way to handle this.

Instead have the 2nd `bind` choose its own listening port.  To do this you specify port 0 in your address struct passed to `bind`.  The system will then choose a listening port for you rather than everything being hardcoded to run on 8889.  You obviously then have to tell the client (via the control connection established in pthread1) "hey, connect to me on this port to transfer data" and the client, in turn, has to establish the connection.  From your outline above you will need to make a few design changes to accomplish that.

Another way is obviously to just to keep your hard coded 8889 listening port but only bind to it once.  This has some issues but if this is just an exercise it is obviously easy to implement.

Caveat: it's been a long time since I thought about FTP servers but this is the basic outline of passive mode.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I'm going to try this and tell you about the results.

Comment: Now i Edited my code : i made a for loop going from 1025 to 40000, then i send the port number to the client after being sure that binding is well done, all clients now can be connected as i wanted,Thank you so much.

Comment: @badr assa - that's on the ugly side and inefficient but if you handle the `bind` errors and skip over the ports already in use it will work.  Suggest you switch to the method I suggested above if you run into problems.  Pass `bind` a 0 port and then retrieve the port it assigns you with `getsockname`.  It's cleaner.  In any case I am glad you are on your way.  Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

The data exchange port used by thread-2 should be a random port selected beforehand during the session acknowledgement performed with the client by thread-1.

---

Also you might be better off running the threads detached, so there is no need to join them, as in the current design joining blocks at least the main server.